# How would one derive conclusions from this?

Tags: logic

Using only the 18 rules of inference without CP or IP derive the conclusion

1. (x)(Ax ⊃ Bx)
2. (x)(Bx ⊃ Cx)   / (x)(Ax ⊃ Cx)

As well as when using an Existential Quantifier

1. (x)(Bx ⊃ Cx)
2. (∃x)(Ax & Bx) / (∃x)(Ax & Cx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the rules of your proof system are but I'm sure you get the gist of it.

1.(x)(Ax ⊃ Bx)

2.(x)(Bx ⊃ Cx) / (x)(Ax ⊃ Cx)

3...........flag a (for UG)

4...........Aa ⊃ Ba...........1 UI

5...........Ba ⊃ Ca...........2 UI

6...........Aa ⊃ Ca............4,5 HS

7.(x)(Ax ⊃ Cx)...............6 UG

---

1.(x)(Bx ⊃ Cx)

2.(∃x)(Ax & Bx) / (∃x)(Ax & Cx)

3.Aa & Ba...................2 ∃I (flag a)

4.Ba⊃Ca......................1 UI

5.Ba..............................3 Simp

6.Ca..............................4,5 MP

7.Aa...............................3 Simp

8.Aa&Ca........................6,7 Conj

9.(∃x)(Ax & Cx)............8 ∃G